# modular arithmetic problems

Tags: java, algorithm, modular-arithmetic

i met a problem from an easy algorithm. The question is below:

Problem description
The recursive formula of Fibonacci sequence is: Fn=Fn-1+Fn-2, where F1=F2=1.

### When n is large, Fn is also very large, and now we want to know what the remainder of Fn over 10007 is.

Input format

### The input contains an integer n.

The output format

### The output line contains an integer representing the remainder of Fn divided by 10007.

The sample input
10
Sample output

### 55

The sample input
22
Sample output

### 7704

Data size and convention
1 <= n <= 1,000,000.

my solution is below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

/**
 *
 */
public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println(recurrence(n));
    in.close();

}


/**
 *
 * @param n
 * @return
 */
public static int recurrence(int n) {
    int f1 = 1;
    int f2 = 1;
    int temp = f1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n - 2; i++) {
        temp = (f1 + f2)%10007;
        f1 = f2;
        f2 = temp;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

}

The solution above is right. But i wanna say the following solution has a problem.

```
public static int recurrence(int n) {
    int f1 = 1;
    int f2 = 1;
    int temp = f1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n - 2; i++) {
        f1 %= 10007;
        f2 %= 10007;
        temp = f1 + f2;
        f1 = f2;
        f2 = temp;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

is not `temp = (f1+f2)%10007` the same as `f1 %= 10007; f2 %= 10007; temp = f1 + f2;`？

My English is poor, i hope you guys can understand what i mean. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like it's more a mathematical problem rather than a programming one.

Comment: (f1 % 10007) + (f2 % 10007) can be up to 20012

Comment: @MattTimmermans, yes, while the greatest remainder of division of `(f1 + f2)` on 10007 will be 10006.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are certain properties for rewriting modulo result. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Properties_(identities)) shows some of them. The one that's relevant here is:

```
(a + b) % n = ((a % n) + (b % n)) % n
```

So if you change

F<sub>n</sub> = F<sub>n-1</sub> + F<sub>n-2</sub>

to

F<sub>n</sub> = (F<sub>n-1</sub> + F<sub>n-2</sub>) % 10007

you get what you want, since F<sub>n-1</sub> and F<sub>n-2</sub> have already had the `% 10007` applied.

```
static int fibMod(int n, int mod) {
    if (n < 0 || mod < 2)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    if (n <= 1)
        return n;
    int prev = 1, fib = 1;
    for (int i = 3; i <= n; i++)
        fib = (prev + (prev = fib)) % mod;
    return fib;
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(fibMod(10, 10007));
System.out.println(fibMod(22, 10007));
System.out.println(fibMod(1_000_000, 10007));
```

*Output*

```
55
7704
114
```

Comment: Thanks, friend. i see. may be this is a mathematical question. haha~